# Show that the weights in IWLS algorithm are always 1

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, variance, algorithms

I have a data for fire insurance with a model with the responce variable Y claim size and there are two potential predictor. I have to fit the linear additive model
$$E(log Y_i)=\beta_0+\beta x_{i,grp}+\beta_{sum} log X_{i,sum}$$
This have I done.

Then I got that the normal regression model is also a genralized linear with a log-link and a quadratic variance function. This is given as
$$log E(Y_i)=\tilde{\beta_0}+\beta x_{i,grp}+\beta_{sum} log X_{i,sum}$$

Then I have to show that a log-link and a quadric variance function $\nu(\mu)=\mu^2$, then the weights in IWLS algorithm are always 1.
I'm not sure how to show this. I don't understand the IWLS totally it have not been explaned in the lectures. But I think that the working weights are given by $W^{0}=diag(w_1,w_2...,w_n)$ and $w_i=\frac{1}{a(\phi_i)(g'(\mu_i^{(0)}))^2V(\mu_i^{0})}$

Hope anyone can help me to understand

Comment: Focus your efforts on understanding the functional form of the weights

Comment: Yes I have not understand the notation of the weights form. I have try to read it but I can't understand it. It a bit difficult when it's not explaned in my lectures. Can you or another help me?

Comment: What have you tried reading?